# chriso/klein regex in URL

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to add a regex to a klein URL, that will allow for a capital or a slash afterwards.

```
$klein->respond('GET', '@([Hh]ome[\\/]?)', function() {
    return 'Home';
});
```

However this regex isn't working for me - it doesn't recognise it at all.

I have also tried it without the slashing at the end, so that it will just recognise the capital, like so:

```
'@([Hh]ome)'
```

Basically i'm wanting it to be able to do the following:

site.com/home

site.com/home/

site.com/Home

site.com/Home/

Comment: If you write the `@` in the regex, it has to be there in the actual text. https://regex101.com/r/dA8rU8/1 works fine, or am i missing something that you need.

Comment: @andrisleduskrasts according to the docs you need to preceed any custom regex with the  '@' symbol: https://github.com/chriso/klein.php#routing

Answer (score 0):

`([Hh]ome[\\/]?)`

is not a valid regular expression. The problem is the character class at the end, i.e., `[\\/]`. Slash (`/`) needs to be escaped, but you don't do that by escaping the backslash (escape) character (`\`). The regular expression you've written is invalid and I'm surprised it's not throwing an error. (Are you sure it isn't?)

Anyway, you're trying to say "optional trailing slash," which could just be written as `\/?`. Note how we escape the slash. If you wanted to use a character class instead, you'd put exactly that inside the square brackets, like so: `[\/]`.

This regex ought to do it.

`[Hh]ome\/?`

See here: https://regex101.com/r/kT2fQ1/1

Comment: This isn't the problem unfortunately (I agree with your reasoning, however even with completely removing the last part of the regex and leaving [Hh]ome there it doesn't work even with that.
The double backslash came from using AltoRouter, where you have to escape the escape character